# Describing c with ebnf grammar

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ebnf

This is a grammar in EBNF to describe C:

```
stmt->  (CASE CONST ‘:’)* expression ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* IF ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt [ELSE stmt]
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* WHILE ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* SWITCH ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* RETURN [expression] ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* BREAK ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* CONTINUE ‘;’
      | ‘{’ (stmt)* ‘}’
```

I want to modify the above with these restrictions:

1. The CASE labelcan only be used on commands that are directly contained in a command SWITCH, and not inside its nested IF or WHILE commands.
2. The BREAK command can only appear inside a WHILE command or one
   SWITCH command, including these nested commands.
3. The CONTINUE command can only appear inside a WHILE command,
   including nested commands.

My answer:

```
stmt-> ( CONST ‘:’)* expression ‘;’
     | ( CONST ‘:’)* IF ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt [ELSE stmt]
     | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* SWITCH ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt
     | ( CONST ‘:’)* WHILE ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt
     | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* BREAK ‘;’
     | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* CONTINUE ‘;’
     | ( CONST ‘:’)* RETURN [expression] ‘;’
     | ‘{’ (stmt)* ‘}’
```

Is this right?

Comment: `stmt-> ( CONST ‘:’)* expression ‘;’` definitely does not make much sense... the whole grammar does not make much sense to be honest. Just have a `switch_stmt` and then define that separately, don't wrap every single possible statement into a `(CASE CONST ':')*`, that is just confusing.

Comment: Note that applying the restrictions you propose is changing the language from C to C- (a smaller subset of C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you face up is very complicated.  As an approach (I don't think there's enough place here to explain it fully) you can first start writting to similar `stmt` nonterminals, one that accepts `case` statements on it, and one that doesn't.  They must be both derived from the original `stmt` you have posted.

```
stmt_w_case ->  (CASE CONST ‘:’)* expression ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* IF ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt [ELSE stmt]
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* WHILE ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* SWITCH ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* RETURN [expression] ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* BREAK ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* CONTINUE ‘;’
      | ‘{’ (stmt)* ‘}’

stmt_wo_case ->  expression ‘;’
      | IF ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt [ELSE stmt]
      | WHILE ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt
      | SWITCH ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt
      | RETURN [expression] ‘;’
      | BREAK ‘;’
      | CONTINUE ‘;’
      | ‘{’ (stmt)* ‘}’
```

Now you said that you wanted `stmt_w_case` inside `switch` statements only, then the while `stmt` should be changed into `stmt_w_case` while all the others must be changed into `stmt_wo_case`, as

```
stmt_w_case ->  (CASE CONST ‘:’)* expression ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* IF ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt_wo_case [ELSE stmt_wo_case]
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* WHILE ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt_wo_case
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* SWITCH ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt_w_case
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* RETURN [expression] ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* BREAK ‘;’
      | (CASE CONST ‘:’)* CONTINUE ‘;’
      | ‘{’ (stmt_w_case)* ‘}’

stmt_wo_case ->  expression ‘;’
      | IF ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt_wo_case [ELSE stmt_wo_case]
      | WHILE ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt_wo_case
      | SWITCH ‘(’ expression ‘)’ stmt_w_case
      | RETURN [expression] ‘;’
      | BREAK ‘;’
      | CONTINUE ‘;’
      | ‘{’ (stmt_wo_case)* ‘}’
```

(see how `stmt_wo_case` propagates it's condition to the embedded `stmt` between brackets `{` and `}` and similarly for the `stmt_w_case`)

Then you can say:

```
stmt -> stmt_wo_case
```

and your grammar is ready (but probably you'll run in trouble later, see below)

In the case of the `break` statement, you should do the same with the new grammar, but be careful, as in this case you can have a `break` well nested in any of the statements of a `if` statement or similar.  For each of the rules we have just forked two.... you need to do a different `stmt_w_case_no_break` and a `stmt_w_case_w_break` (and the same for `stmt_wo_case...`) and do you see where does this bring us?  in each place we want some kind of rule with, and without, we are doubling the number of rules.... you grow exponentially with the number of decisions of this type you make.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I would be grateful if you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320002/semantic-analysis-of-a-grammar-with-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

> Is this right?

No. The grammar show merely says things like “Only `switch`, `break`, and `continue` can have `case some-constant :` labels, while the others can have `some-constant :`.

To say that a `case` label can only be used on commands that are directly inside a `switch`, the body of a switch, or presumably the body of a compound statement that is the body of a switch, must be a statement or list of statements of a type that can have `case` labels, whereas the statements or list of statements that appear elsewhere must be statements of a type that cannot have `case` labels.

So define a grammar token like `MayBeLabeledStatement` that can have a `case` label and another grammar token like `Statement` that cannot have a `case` label. Both statements may expand to the various kinds of statements (expression, `if`, `while`, and so on), but the ones for `MayBeLabeledStatement` also may have `case` labels. Further, all the statements **within** a `MayBeLabeledStatement` should be `Statement` type statements, which cannot have `case` labels—except you may need to think about how to handle the single statement inside a `switch` (which could be a compound statement or not).

Similarly, you will need different grammar tokens to handle statements inside a `while` or `switch` (which allow `break`) versus those not inside a `while` or `switch` and another for those within a `while` (which allow `continue)` versus those not inside a `while`. You may also need some combinations, for statements that are inside a `while` and are directly inside a `switch` versus statements that are inside a `while` and are not directly inside a `switch`.